# Should a Database Update be sent for publication in same journal where previous edition was published?

Tags: publications, authorship, databases

My lab published a database (db) two years back in Nuclear Acids Research. Now looking at the increasing data and new features we are planning to update the db. but the db admin is leaving now and I have taken full charge over it.

1. Is it mandatory for us to send the update to same journal (*so as to increase chance of acceptance*)
2. What authorship may I expect? (*1st or 2nd*)

Comment: Hey! I expect your question (and the title) are too specific to attract a lot of views, and consequently, answers. You might try reformulation it in something along the lines "Should an update/extension to a paper (method/structure/database/or whatever) be published in the same place as the original?" and making a more general question that appeals to more people. Also, clarifying your contribution (v.s. the old admin) for the _new_ version might be useful

Comment: FYI: Nuclear Acids Research is pretty much the go to journal for bioinformatics related databases (at least it used to be; I left the field a while ago).

Answer (score 4):

Nothing ties you, neither ethically nor legally, to publish your new work (your database update) in the same journal as earlier work on the topic. However, if the journal was a good venue for this particular publication some years ago, the same reasons probably still hold, which means it's still a good place to publish your update. If, however, you feel like changing, just go for it!

Regarding authorship, this should be discussed right now. If you have full charge of the database, did important work on it yourself, and write the paper, then **you have strong arguments to be first author**. On the other hand, if you're the new admin but contributed little to the recent improvements, your position is weaker. In the end, it will be the result of a negotiation.

Comment: Thanks. The actual improvement part is starting now and I will be responsible for updates. It's a 3 month job to me.